# BeforeSuite testnG parameter is null with maven run

Tags: maven, testng

My testNG looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="ParseTestbed" parallel="false">
    <parameter name="testbed-properties-file" value="src/test/resources/testbedInfo.properties" />

    <test name="ParseTestbedVC">
        <classes>
            <parameter name="testbed-path" value="testbeds/vc/testbedInfo.json" />
            <parameter name="prop-key" value="vc.ip" />
            <class name="com.vmware.vcloud.suite.common.ParseTestbedInfo">
                <methods>
                    <include name="writeVCProperties" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My test class looks like:

```
public class BaseTest {
public static String propertiesFile;

@BeforeSuite
@Parameters({ "testbed-properties-file" })
public void loadProperties(@Optional String propertiesFs) {
      System.out.println(propertiesFs);
}
}
```

***ParseTestbedInfo extends BaseTest class***

I am able to run and print the value of the parameter from eclipse. But I am getting ***null*** value while running throu maven.

The command I am executing in maven is:

```
mvn clean install -Dtestngfile.path=src/test/resources/parse-testbed.xml
```

Where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The surefire param you should use is [`suiteXmlFiles`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#suiteXmlFiles) with `surefire.suiteXmlFiles` as user property.

Comment: I do not understand you suggestion. can you give one example?

Comment: Where do you find `-Dtestngfile.path`? It is not the user property you should use to provide testng.xml. In other word, I suppose it doesn't work and testng won't find your tests, as expected.